# Ogr2ogr: how to add values ​to a database column

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, php

So I have my table named ppb_curp with the following columns

```
ogc_fid | name | description | wkb_geometry |curp | zip_code
```

Then I insert the KML file in my PostGis base with ogr2ogr

```
ogr2ogr  -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgis_24_sample port=5432 user=postgres password=123456"   C:\xampp\htdocs\siap-padron\public\uploads/2044492/polygon/1597861175.kml  -nln  ppb_curp  2>&1
```

but just insert data into column ogc_fid and wkb_geometry.

i am using php as language, the values ​​of name, description, curp,zip_code I have them in a variable:

```
$name = "My kml file";
$description = "My kml file description";
$curp = "2JJIDEIEIEI";
$zip_code = "89790";
```

My question is how do I insert these fields with Ogr2ogr?

The command line with ogr2ogr is:

```
ogr2ogr  -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgis_24_sample port=5432 user=postgres password=123456"   C:\xampp\htdocs\siap-padron\public\uploads/2044492/kml/1597889056.kml  -nln  ppb_curp  -dialect sqlite  -sql "SELECT ogc_fid, 'My kml file' as name FROM 'ppb_curp'" 2>&1
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ogc_fid, 'Hello Ogr2ogr' as name FROM 'ppb_curp'): no such table: ppb_curp
```

Comment: So you execute `ogr2ogr` from within PHP, meaning that you prepare the shell script as string? If so, you could use sth. like `ogr2ogr <other_options> -dialect sqlite -sql 'SELECT ogc_fid, <name> AS name, <desc> AS description, <curp> AS curp, <zip> AS zip_code, GEOMETRY AS wkb_geometry FROM <layer_name>;'` where you pass in string literals from your vars.

Comment: Exact, the string I generate from php @geozelot update my question with the string I generate with your answer. output; `ogr2ogr  -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgis_24_sample port=5432 user=postgres password=123456"   C:\xampp\htdocs\siap-padron\public\uploads/2044492/polygon/1597861175.kml  -nln  ppb_curp  -dialect sqlite  -sql "SELECT ogc_fid, 'My kml file ' as name FROM 'ppb_curp'" 2>&1`  ,  but how do I get the value of layer_name ?

Comment: `<layer_name>` is refering to the *input* file! Try with the name of the KML file you import from, i.e. `... FROM "1597889056";`.

Comment: @geozelot  I have changed my command line but I still get `no such table: 1597889056`, with `ogrinfo -al -so 1597889056.kml` return  `Layer name: LOBR640610MZSNTB09 Geometry:Unknown (any) Feature Count: 1`, is there a way to get layer_name from ogr2ogr or change the value ?